# python check if list items is in string

Tags: python

```
link = 'http://dedegood.com'
wrongdomain = ['google','facebook','twitter']


if any(link.find(i) for i in wrongdomain):
    print 'pass this url'
else:
    print 'good'
```

I want to check if `link` contains the words in `wrongdomain`
Why this always print `'pass this url'`?
`link` has no google or facebook or twitter in it
I try seperate like  `link.find('google')`
it will return -1 .so what's the problem?

Please help me to check my logic.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bool(-1)` is `True` in Python. Instead of find, you can just do:

```
if any(domain in link for domain in wrongdomain):
```

Just remember that will also match the rest of the url, not just the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will not work correctly like a url like `http://dedegood.com/google` this. So you can use something like;

```
link = 'http://dedegood.com'
wrongdomain = ['google','facebook','twitter']

a=link.split("//")
b=a[1].split(".")
if any(domain in b[0] for domain in wrongdomain):
     print ('pass this url')
else:
    print ('good')
```

Since you just want to check url, you can use this one. Instead of checking all link, it's checking only the name of website. So if any url like `http://dedegood.com/google` will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know whether the url's domain is in wrongdomain or not? I would suggest you can do this for better performance:

```
import urlparse
import tldextract

link = 'http://dedegood.com'
wrongdomain = ['google','facebook','twitter']
parsed = tldextract.extract(link)
if parsed.domain in wrongdomain:
    print 'pass this url'
else:
    print 'good'
```

You could check out tldextract, a library designed to get domain from a url.